# Не задаётся фон-градиент на Vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, background

У меня имеются два метода, которые задают фон отдельному блоку.
Первый метод задаёт сплошной фон, а второй - градиент.
Сами цвета лежат в data.

```
setColor() {
    this.$refs.bannerImage.style.background = this.banner.bgColor.solo
},
setGradient() {
    this.$refs.bannerImage.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, "+ this.banner.bgColor.gradient.firstColor +","+ this.banner.bgColor.gradient.secondColor +");"
}
```

Проблема в том, что метод со сплошным цветом работает как надо, а с градиентом не задаётся, будто метода и не существует (если в нём же прописать ...background = 'null' - всё работает, так что проблема не с его вызовом). Причём никакой ошибки в консоли не наблюдается

Все прописанные пути правильные, проверил уже по 100 раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"linear-gradient(to right, "+ this.banner.bgColor.gradient.firstColor +","+ this.banner.bgColor.gradient.secondColor +");"
```

; - не нужен в конце строки.

Comment: и на это я потратил целый час...
Спасибо!